# How to start Zoom meeting automatically from C# Console Application

Tags: c#, browser, process

I am trying to build a simple app (As Console Application) that enters a Zoom meeting automatically at a specified time.

The app opens the Zoom meeting using `Process.Start` function, and then wait for the "Zoom Meeting" process to start.

It works well if I use a Windows shortcut file (.lnk extension) with the correct parameters, [like shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line)

But is doesn't work when I use the "regular" Zoom link (the url) because it opens the browser and waits for user input (It shows an alert).

I know how to send input to a process, so all I need is to a reference to the browser window that opened, but I can't find it.

The `Process.Start` doesn't return it and when I looped through all processes (`Process.GetProcesses`) I couldn't find any useful name that I can search for.

So, how can I get a reference to the browser process? Or at least send it input when it start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using a browser you need to connect to a URL using the Navigate method().

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the respones, where can I find this method?

Comment: webbrowser1.Navigate("URL");  What type of project are you using?  Try a Form application and add the browser control.

Comment: @jdweng I forgot to write, I am using a Console application to launch the meeting.
The WebBrowser works on WinForms application but on Console app nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=== **EDIT** ===

After digging in Windows Registry, I have found an even simpler code to achieve it:

```
public static void OpenZoomMeeting(string link)
{
    string zoomDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%APPDATA%\Zoom\bin");
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = $@"{zoomDirectory}\Zoom.exe",
        Arguments = $"--url={link}",
        WorkingDirectory = zoomDirectory
    };
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

=== **OLD CODE** ===

Found the solution thanks to [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)

He said that I should to use a `WebBrowser` to open the meeting without the prompt, so I looked into it.

Because my app is a Console Application, I can't just use a `WebBrowser` so I found [That solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581) and it worked for me.

Thank you for your help

===**The code**===

```
private void RunBrowserThread(string url) {
    var th = new Thread(() => {
        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += Browser_DocumentCompleted;
        br.Navigate(url);
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (br.Url == e.Url) {
        Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
        Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
    }
}
```