# Toggle Audio-Output On/Off within Zoom Meetings (MacOS)

Tags: javascript, applescript

I attend several recurring Zoom meetings every day and would like to control Zoom’s audio output. I need a AppleScript or JavaScript to toggle On / Off Zoom audio without changing it at MacOS [System Level] only in Zoom App.

I use Zoom Output "Select a Speaker" according to the following options:

**Audio-On**  = Build-In Output (Internal Speaker) /

**Audio-Off** = NDI Audio *(not in operation)*

To accomplish this I use the following steps:

1. Select the Zoom Window
2. Locate Mic botton
3. Select the options feature [⋀]
4. Select a Speaker "alternative" to activate/deactivate audio.

Zoom has a [Mute-Mic] but no [Mute-Spkr] button. It would be nice to have this handy, when you need to answer a phone call.

[Zoom screen with keystones to change Speaker options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IScYY.png)

Comment: **Stack Overflow** is not a code writing service! Also, please do not post the same question on multiple **Stack Exchange** sites (https://superuser.com/questions/1686959/toggle-audio-output-on-off-within-zoom-meetings) What have you tried so far and were is it failing to achieve the results wanted?

Comment: @Stack Overflow, apologies for not knowing in advance that superuser.com was a paid question / answer site. Understanding that, I proceeded to post the question on Stack Overflow, where I assumed to find an answer. I regret that I neglected to understand what you were doing.

I expected a simple 1-2 line script that might also help others.

Comment: Assumed that my question was similar to the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803548/how-to-start-zoom-meeting-automatically-from-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your Zoom.app window.
2. Open Automator
3. Select Create new Workflow or Create new Action
4. Press **RED button**. This will activate **Automator recording window** of all your following manual actions.
5. Accomplish manually 4 actions you described in the question.
6. Close Automator recording window
7. Drag written by Automator actions down to code area. One by one. **This will show you its scripts.** Remains copying the useful content from the script generated by the Automator. And cleaning the external quotes and escapes.

For example: I wrote using the Automator my click action on the current webpage.

Here is generated Automator code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Mouse Clicked
    delay 7.956482
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
    set uiScript to "click group 1 of list 2 of group 8 of UI Element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"javascript - Toggle Audio-Output On/Off within Zoom Meetings (MacOS) - Stack Overflow\" of application process \"Safari\""
    my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
    return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

I take from the script above only this useful content. As you can see I grab only the correct UI action (**the value of uiScript variable**) :

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true -- required
    click group 1 of list 2 of group 8 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "javascript - Toggle Audio-Output On/Off within Zoom Meetings (MacOS) - Stack Overflow"
end tell
```

Comment: Robert, Thank you very much for your answer. I used your technique to make the script, but I found a problem that some of the parameters are static and if I run it a few days later, they no longer match.   

Script variation between different sessions:  
Yesterday:  
set uiScript to "click UI Element 12 of window \"Zoom Meeting\" of application process \"zoom.us\""  


Today:  
set uiScript to "click UI Element 3 of window \"Zoom Webinar Panelist(25)  Attendee(110)\" of application process \"zoom.us\""  

Is there any dynamic alternative I can use?